# PHP SQL query not pulling expected results

Tags: php, sql

I have a query like so:

```
SELECT `value` FROM `thisTable` WHERE (`field` = 'category' AND `value` = '$catvalue') OR (`field` = 'subcat' AND `value` > '') GROUP BY `name_id` HAVING count(*) >= '2'
```

This is pulling data from thisTable:

```
------------------------------
| name_id | field    | value |
------------------------------
| 1       | category | cat1  |
| 1       | subcat   | sub3  |
| 2       | category | cat1  |
| 2       | subcat   | sub2  |
| 3       | category | cat1  |
| 3       | subcat   | sub1  |
------------------------------
```

My query works perfectly in PHPMyAdmin in that it lists the values of the subcategories. BUT when I try to pull the same thing in my PHP query I just get the values of the categories.

So PHPMyAdmin would show `sub3, sub2, sub1` which is what I want but my query would show `cat1, cat1, cat1`!

My code is the same query as above but results are different.

```
$result = $connect->query("SELECT `value` FROM `thisTable` WHERE (`field` = 'category' AND `value` = '$catvalue') OR (`field` = 'subcat' AND `value` > '') GROUP BY `name_id` HAVING count(*) >= '2'");
while($data = $result->fetch()) {
    $array[] = $data['value'];
}
```

I can't see where to go next to get the results that PHPMyAdmin is showing!
I'm guessing it's something to do with `fetch()` but that's as far as I get.

Thanks in advance for any insights!

UPDATE: What about doing this as a JOIN to itself? How would I do that? This is the only other thought I've had to get it to work.

Comment: That first query is invalid. Strangely you get an invalid result instead of an error, with 3 columns while you're only selecting one... Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Can't find the 'edit question' option! In the query where it says `cat` it should say `category`.
@jarlh I'm using mysql - why is my query invalid?

Comment: "Can't find the 'edit question' option! "... the "edit" button is right under the little blue buttons saying "php" and "sql". Or click here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50909900/edit

Comment: What if I did this as a join to itself? That's my only other thought, though not sure how I would do that.

Comment: Anyway what is the value of `$catvalue` when you run the query in PHP. Double-check that - since that's the main difference to what you run in PhpMyAdmin. BTW is this MySQL in the backend?

Comment: Also show us how you're printing the results in case it's something to do with that.

Comment: @ADyson $catvalue is 'cat1'

Comment: @ADyson Array is being sent as json but regardless of how it's printed it is showing a list of categories rather than subcategories. For some reason it is choosing to show the value for categories rather than the value for subcategories, which I don't get when phpMyAdmin is showing it the way I want it.

Comment: "My query works perfectly in PHPMyAdmin" - could you show the table results from that?

Comment: @CFPSupport See the text just underneath where I say that - it shows the output: `sub3, sub2, sub1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is *an* answer! But not what it should be.
I decided to split the query into two:

- first pull the category...

  SELECT `name_id` FROM `thisTable` WHERE `field` = 'category' AND `value` = '$catvalue'
- then pull the subcategories inside that

  SELECT `value` FROM `thisTable` WHERE `name_id` = '$name_id' AND `field` = 'subcat' AND `value` != ''

Not the most concise solution but it works :)